# The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "<nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

We are running a PowerShell script on our farm at the moment to pull all the users and their permissions. The script is working fine on all of our sites, but one is giving us the following error:

```
The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: 
"<nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>".
At line:5 char:5
+     $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups | Select Name, Owner, Users
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

This seems to be throwing off our ability to output the data to a CSV file. So my question if you lovely people could answer is What would cause this? And how would we find out what it is related to?

Below is the script we are using to pull the data:

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://localhost | Get-SPSite -Limit All | where {($_.RootWeb.WebTemplateId -ne 54) -and ($_.RootWeb.WebTemplateId -ne 21)} | % {
  $site = $_
  $site.RootWeb.Url
  $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
  $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups | Select Name, Owner, Users
  #$site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions | Select Name, BasePermissions
}

$groups = $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups

function Get-SPGroup() {
  foreach ($grp in $groups) {
    foreach ($user in $grp.users) {
      $hash = @{"URL" = $site.Rootweb.url; "Group" = $grp.name; "User" = $user.name}
      New-Object PSObject -Property $hash | Sort-Object
    }
  }
}

Get-SPGroup | Export-csv C:\Users\*****\Desktop\permissions-list.csv

$Site.Dispose()
```

Help please before I go mental :(

Comment: Can you check if you have appropriate permissions on this site?

Comment: I do, I am running this with the farm account with this, I am also able to run the script on other site collections as the farm account and on my own account.

Comment: Can you access that site, maybe it is orphaned.

Comment: The script works fine for me. Yes, check the site or the groups which you want to export, if there is any orphan or not.

Comment: We can access all the sites that are throwing this message up, we will run a check if there is a correlation between orphaned sites and the error. I will update in min. PERFECT!!! They are Orphaned , that might be it, we are going to fix the sites and come back to you, thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: Great to hear that!

Comment: So Update, We have run some PowerShell odd and sods to fix the orphaned bits and pieces, which is great and has certainly fixed those. But these errors still seem to be appearing... If we run a different script at an individual site level  this does return the results, this doesn't really work for us as we have 150+ sites to run it on. Is there anything else that could cause this something to do with it reading the permissions on the site maybe?

Comment: I have Updated this script to remove the errors but the system is now not outputting the data to the csv file.